# How to Filter json data with python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, filter

I am trying to create a function that filters json data pulled from the Google places api. I want it to return the name of a business and the types values if the name contains the string "Body Shop" and the types are ['car_repair', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment'] otherwise I want it to reject the result. Here is my code so far. I have tried and tried and can't seem to figure out a way to store certain criteria to make the search easier.

```
import googlemaps
import pprint
import time
import urllib.request  






API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
lat, lng = 40.35003, -111.95206

#define our Client
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)
#Define our Search
places_result = gmaps.places_nearby(location= "40.35003,-111.95206", radius= 40000,open_now= False,type= ['car_repair','point_of_interest','establishment'])
#pprint.pprint(places_result['results'])
time.sleep(3)
places_result_2 = gmaps.places_nearby(page_token = 
places_result['next_page_token'])
pprint.pprint(places_result_2['results'])

places_result_2 = gmaps.places_nearby(page_token = 
places_result['next_page_token'])
    
types = place_details['result']['types']
name = place_details['result']['name']
def match(types,name):
  for val in types: 
      'car_repair','point_of_interest','establishment' in val and "Body Shop" in name
print(name,types)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import googlemaps
import pprint
import time
import urllib.request  




API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
lat, lng = 40.35003, -111.95206

#define our Client
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)
#Define our Search

places_result = gmaps.places_nearby(location= "40.35003,-111.95206", radius= 40000,open_now= False,type= ['car_repair','point_of_interest','establishment'])


#heres how to retrieve the name of the first result
example_of_name = places_result['results'][0]['name']
print(example_of_name)

#gets places name and type for all the results
for place in places_result['results']:
  print("Name of Place:")
  print(place['name'])
  print("Type of the place:")
  print(place['types'], "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem! I couldn't replicate the problem myself, gmaps says the places_nearby module doesn't exist. If you still have the problem, I can probably help further with more info.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the code to add the actual pulling of the json result from the API. I think what I'm really trying to accomplish is storing multiple criteria in a single variable in python so that I can reject any data that doesn't match the criteria. I think an equivalent in Javascript would be creating a const array or at least that's what a friend who doesn't know python said.

Comment: The problem is that one of the criteria for the filter would need to be 'name' and each business name is obviously going to be different so I don't know how to store that (That's why you see that I tried to filter results if they had the string "Body Shop" in them. But it's obviously not working.

Comment: Hey there! I see your issue. It's because the google puts the json info into a list when you import it. It's pretty subtle, but it lets you iterate more easily. I've updated my code so that should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just actually came to a similar conclusion but your code is much neater than mine. Thanks again for all the help on this.